# Doorbell resistor across front & trans - safe for Nest? Purpose?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

Any idea what purpose this resistor serves in our doorbell chime and if it's okay to keep it on there when installing a Nest doorbell or if I should remove it? I'm assuming this is a resistor but am not certain - maybe a diode?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a resistor.  Do you have a multimeter...?

Comment: That's a diode, not a resistor.

Comment: That is a diode the stripe is the - or cathode the other side is the anode. Diodes block the ac in 1 direction creating pulsating DC. Some lighted buttons need a diode to change the ac from the transformer to dc for an LED.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes - I have a multimeter - anything I should measure?  Btw, the chime is not working (never has worked).

Comment: @EdBeal the diode is used to power "fancy" chimes, not an LED. A buzzer that only buzzes while the button is depressed doesn't need one. If a button used one for an LED, it would fork off to the lamp and only contact one contact.

Comment: @dandavis I have had to install diodes in the past for illuminated push buttons no diode and that push button only illuminated for a flash the first time,